# how do i format a string that is going to be in a label

Tags: java, javafx

I have a media player and i am putting a listiner on my media player for both the slider value and the time value my question is how do i format the time that i am putting in the label to display as 0:00 the first 0 being the minute the second being 10s of seconds and the third every one second.

```
public void setUpsongDurationSlider()
{
    musicMedia.getMediaPlayer().currentTimeProperty().addListener((obs, oldTme, newTime)->
    {
        homeView.getSongDurationSlider().setValue(newTime.toSeconds());
        homeView.getSongDurationSliderLabel().setText(Double.toString((newTime.toMinutes())));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply retrieve the minutes/seconds from the `Duration` object and use `String.format` to pad the seconds...

The following example only prints to `System.out` and uses a property created in the code, but you should be able to adjust it for your purpose:

```
ObjectProperty<Duration> duration = new SimpleObjectProperty(Duration.ZERO);

duration.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(String.format("%d:%02d",
            (long)newValue.toMinutes(),
            ((long) newValue.toSeconds()) % 60));
});

// test for 1-99 seconds
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    duration.set(Duration.seconds(i));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

so that other post helped but it is a double value that needed to be converted so i needed to use "%f" instead of "%d".

```
musicMedia.getMediaPlayer().currentTimeProperty().addListener((obs, oldTme, newTime)->
        {
            homeView.getSongDurationSlider().setValue(newTime.toSeconds());
            homeView.getSongDurationSliderLabel().setText(String.format("%.2f min",(newTime.toMinutes())));
```

Comment: `0.50 min` for 30 seconds? That's not what you asked for in the question!